# how to list current path mode?

Tags: linux, shell

If the current path is `/data/db_1`, and `/data` has three subpath, `db_1, db_2, db_3`.

I want to know `db_1`’s modification, owner and group.

Currently I use `ls -li /data |grep db_1` , but I think there must better way to do it?

Comment: Why not just `ls -lid /data/db_1` if you know the name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see the permissions of the current directory, whatever it is, use:

```
ls -lid .
```

How it works:

- `-l` asks `ls` for a long directory listing.
- `-i` asks `ls` for inode information (optional).
- `-d` tells `ls` to report on the directory itself, not what is in it.
- `.` refers, as is conventional for Unix, to the current directory.

Because [POSIX `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) supports the `-l`, `-i`, and `-d` options, this method is portable.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `ls` at all. It is [generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to try and parse `ls` output and there are other tools that are specifically designed for the job. In this case, you can use `stat`:

```
$ stat -c '%G %U %y' .
terdon terdon 2015-03-03 19:37:48.007033824 +0200
```

#### Explanation

```
   -c  --format=FORMAT
          use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output  a  new‐
          line after each use of FORMAT

   %G     group name of owner
   %U     user name of owner
   %y     time of last modification, human-readable
```

So, the command above will print the user (`%U`), group (`%G`) and modification time (`%y`) of `.`, the current directory. It can also print other pieces of information, pretty much anything you will ever need. See `man stat` for more.

Comment: Who says he's trying to parse the output, I think he just wants to view it.

Comment: @Barmar `ls -li /data |grep db_1` _is_ parsing the output of `ls`. What if you have a file or directory called `foo\ndb_1`? Or `db1 and db2`? Anyway, `stat` is specifically designed for this and is the better tool for the job.